# Como obtener la hora, mediante un textbox

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy desarrollando algo similar a una agenda de actividades, en la cual el usuario puede escoger los días en los que desea que la agenda aplique así como también las actividades de la misma, el problema que tengo es que en la agenda el usuario debe escoger la hora en la que inicia su agenda por ejemplo el usuario ingresa en un textbox que sus actividades empiecen a las 8:23 am. entonces el programa debe tomar ese dato y guardarlo para despues desplegarlo en un control datagridview con el nombre de la respectiva actividad.

Ejemplo

---

```
 -actividad - hora-
 ---------------------------
-junta     - 08:23 - 9:30 -
-desayuno  - 09:30 - 10:20-
-etc                      -     
-etc                      -
---------------------------
```

la duración de las actividades ya se encuentran predefinidas asi que no hay problema con eso. El problema como dije, es que no se como guardar la informacion que el usuario ingrese en el textbox y que el programa sepa que se refiere a una hora y no un string por ejemplo.

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkedListBox1.Visible = false;
        comboBox1.Enabled = false;
        comboBox2.Enabled = false;
        textBox2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        DateTime hi = DateTime.ToString("HH:MM");


        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            //this.dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = this.comboBox1.SelectedText;
            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(comboBox1.Text);
            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(hi);
        }
        if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
        {
            //this.dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = this.comboBox1.SelectedText;
            dataGridView3.Rows.Add(comboBox1.Text);
        }
        if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
        {
            //this.dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = this.comboBox1.SelectedText;
            dataGridView4.Rows.Add(comboBox1.Text);
        }
        if (checkBox4.Checked == true)
        {
            //this.dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = this.comboBox1.SelectedText;
            dataGridView5.Rows.Add(comboBox1.Text);
        }
        if (checkBox5.Checked == true)
        {
            //this.dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = this.comboBox1.SelectedText;
            dataGridView6.Rows.Add(comboBox1.Text);
        }

        //MessageBox.Show("Los datos han sido guardados, cambios no permitidos \nPara hacer cambios necesita limpiar los datos \nPulse ''Limpiar Datos'' para hacerlo");
    }
```

Espero y alguien me pueda ayudar. Saludos

Comment: @sstan Listo amigo, gracias por ayudarme, como verás el proceso se realiza hasta que el usuario da click en un botón

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Por qué no usas el [datetimepicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-MX/library/aa983724(v=vs.71).aspx)? Si de todas maneras quieres usarlo con un `textBox` lo que tienes que hacer es convertir tu string de tu `textBox` a `dateTime` (esto en caso de que quieras usarlo para una futura referencia, puedes prescindir de esta conversión) y de igual manera a tu columna deberás agregarle un formato.

```
        tuDGV.Rows.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(tuTextBoxVaAqui.Text,"HH:mm",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        tuDGV.Columns[0/*el número de tu columna acá*/].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm";//<-formato de Horas/minutos
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto era lo que necesitaba :D